# Animate list after fading item and removing it

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example we have such html code:

```
<ul>
    <li id="1">1</li>
    <li id="2">2</li>
    <li id="3">3</li>
    <li id="4">4</li>
</ul>
```

and such js

```
$('#1').fadeOut().remove();
```

after fading out, remaining items simultaneously move up. Is it possible to animate this moving up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `animate` to fade the opacity, then use the callback to execute the `slideUp()` after the fade has finished.

```
$('#1').animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 1000, function() {
    $(this).slideUp();
})
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xSpTG/)